# Can't get MySQL in Docker Compose to respect / read my custom .conf file to load large .sql and allow outside connections

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to create a docker compose file that will automatically load a fairly large (>120mB) .sql upon launch, as well as letting me connect from any IP (From the host machine, not inside the docker container itself) and I'm having nothing but troubles.

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
   db:
      image: mysql:8.0
      container_name: acDB
      restart: always
      ports:
       - '6603:3306'
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: ac_db
        MYSQL_USER: ac
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: ac
        MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'  # needs to be enclosed with quotes
        #MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: 172.26.0.1/255.255.255.248 #Doesn't work either
      volumes:
       - ./db/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/z_my.cnf
       - ./dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
       - ./db/big.sql:/data/application/init.sql
      command: "sudo chown mysql:mysql /etc/mysql/conf.d/z_my.cnf"
      command: "sudo chmod 600 mysql:mysql /etc/mysql/conf.d/z_my.cnf"
      
      command: "mysqld --init-file /data/application/init.sql"

   phpmyadmin:
      depends_on:
       - db
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
      container_name: phpmyadmin
      restart: always
      ports:
       - '8080:80'
      environment:
        PMA_HOST: db
volumes:
  dbdata:
```

My my.cnf:

```
# Config for faster restore DB for development
[mysqld]

pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
#log-error  = /var/log/mysql/error.log
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

bind-address = 0.0.0.0

max_allowed_packet              = 1G
max_connect_errors              = 1000000

# InnoDB Settings
default_storage_engine          = InnoDB
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 2     # Use 1 instance per 1GB of InnoDB pool size
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 1G    # Use up to 70-80% of RAM
innodb_file_per_table           = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 0
innodb_flush_method             = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 16M
innodb_log_file_size            = 512M
innodb_stats_on_metadata        = 0

#innodb_temp_data_file_path     = ibtmp1:64M:autoextend:max:20G # Control the maximum size for the ibtmp1 file
#innodb_thread_concurrency      = 4     # Optional: Set to the number of CPUs on your system (minus 1 or 2) to better
                                        # contain CPU usage. E.g. if your system has 8 CPUs, try 6 or 7 and check
                                        # the overall load produced by MySQL/MariaDB.
innodb_read_io_threads          = 64
innodb_write_io_threads         = 64

# Connection Settings
max_connections                 = 100   # UPD

back_log                        = 512
thread_cache_size               = 100
thread_stack                    = 192K

interactive_timeout             = 180
wait_timeout                    = 180


max_heap_table_size             = 1G
tmp_table_size                  = 1G

[mysqldump]
# Variable reference
# For MySQL 5.7: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html
# For MariaDB:   https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqldump/
quick
quote_names
max_allowed_packet              = 1G
```

When I run it using

*docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d*

The output is:

> 2021-11-03 12:06:14+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for
> MySQL Server 8.0.27-1debian10 started.
>
> 2021-11-03 12:06:15+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated
> user 'mysql'
>
> 2021-11-03 12:06:15+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for
> MySQL Server 8.0.27-1debian10 started.
>
> 2021-11-03T12:06:15.597286Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server]
> 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent)
> is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated
> and will be removed in a future release.
>
> 2021-11-03T12:06:15.597787Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server]
> /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.27) starting as process 1
>
> 2021-11-03T12:06:15.613293Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting
> lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is
> case insensitive
>
> 2021-11-03T12:06:15.661405Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB
> initialization has started.
>
> 2021-11-03T12:06:16.922896Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB
> initialization has ended.
>
> 2021-11-03T12:06:17.438613Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A
> deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
>
> 2021-11-03T12:06:17.438670Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A
> deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
>
> 2021-11-03T12:06:17.446319Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA
> certificate ca.pem is self signed.
>
> 2021-11-03T12:06:17.446643Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel
> mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now
> supported for this channel.
>
> 2021-11-03T12:06:17.457921Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure
> configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path
> is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different
> directory.
>
> 2021-11-03T12:06:18.031214Z 7 [ERROR] [MY-000061] [Server] 1105 Max
> query size reached at file /data/application/init.sql, line 45, query
> started at 45:1 .
>
> 2021-11-03T12:06:18.039134Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin
> ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket:
> /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
>
> 2021-11-03T12:06:18.039292Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server]
> /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.27' socket:
> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' port: 3306 MySQL Community Server - GPL.

The error I get when I try to use phpmyadmin is:

> mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1130): Host '172.30.0.3' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Comment: The name of the mounted configuration file and the actual container configuration file seems to be different. (z_my.cnf in container)
(maybe not because of this)

Comment: Sadly that doesn't seem to change anything, I've tried various names - afaik the original name and the name you're linking to in a volume don't have to be the same.

Comment: Is the currently running mysql configuration file z_my.cnf?

Comment: Looking at the attached log, the max_allowed_packet size is suspected, but my.cnf is set large enough, so I guessed that it was operating with a different configuration file.